# second monitor quit working after I used it to check another computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display

I used my second monitor to check the video card on a pc I just bought that the monitor was not working. The monitor powered up and worked fine, then stopped functioning a day later. 
We have a new monitor that functions well on the pc we bought, however, my second monitor will no longer come on when attached to the pc where it has previously been. 
I have deleted the monitor, rebooted, and the computer detects it fine. I still have a black picture with occasional flicker on the screen. 
What do I do ? OH, its Windows 10 operating system

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware problem, as a detected monitor that worked before should continue
to work.

The monitor was either damaged while being transported, or some difference in the
other video card caused the problem.

You should have the monitor looked at by a professional.
This could be something trivial like a bad connection, a twisted pin,
or something more serious.